# DoveCot users + multiple domains

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

Hi I am trying to get dovecot to work with multiple domains

My /etc/aliases looks like this

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
shop: shop
ben: ben
```

When I try changing it to

`ben@mydomain.com: ben`

and then run

`newaliases`

It tells me

`postalias: warning: /etc/aliases, line 3: name must be local`

Here is my dovecot config

http://178.62.83.203/dovecot.conf

postfix main.cf

http://178.62.83.208/postfix.cf

What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the idea of multiple domains implies that mail users will be virtual. they should not be available in /etc/aliases

instead, you setup Dovecot `userdb`/`passdb` somewhere in `/etc/dovecot/users` or even `/etc/dovecot/%d/users`

in a similar manner define `mail_location` so that it uses `%d`.

in case you need aliases, define them in postfix

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_map
```

and populate the map

```
# /etc/postfix/virtual_alias_map
allusers@domain.org user1@domain.org user2@domain.org ben
```

above `ben` is a local user that exists on the system (in `/etc/passwd`) and the mail will (hopefully) be delivered to user's local mailbox (`/var/mail/ben`)